# How do I undo "always show pictures from this sender" on Android gmail?

Tags: gmail

I accidentally clicked 'Always Display Images from This Sender' ('Always show pictures from this sender' in 2020) and was wondering if there's a way to undo this setting in Android gmail.

It's straightforward to undo on web Gmail, but not the same with Android (that I know of). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In the Android Gmail app,

From the main inbox or inside any email: Bring up the Menu > Settings > General Settings. Now click the Menu button again to bring up sub-menu of options > Clear picture approvals.

**WARNING**: This clears ALL your approved sender settings, I believe there is no option to revoke by individual email senders.

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me. Just to be clear, once on the General settings page, click the three vertical dots(icon) on the top right corner to bring up a popup menu that has the "Clear picture approvals" option. It will display a confirmation prompt that says "Stop displaying inline images from senders you previously allowed." with a CANCEL or CLEAR option.

Answer (score 30):

I needed to clear this setting for a single email address. I followed these steps:

1. Open Gmail (mail.google.com) in a web browser
2. Open an email from the sender which *has* an image in it
3. In the top left of the email it will have the sender's name and below that "*to me*" with a little down arrow next to it
4. Click the little down arrow and then click *Don't display from now on*

[image]

Comment: This seems to be outdated and isn't available for me. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103469/undo-always-display-images-from-this-sender#comment126880_103470

Comment: @Ryan - still works for me. Make sure the email has an image in it

Comment: @RayfenWindspear This is the answer that *I* needed, but it's technically not correct because OP asked specifically about Android.

Comment: Worked for me 2021

Comment: A perfect and illustrative answer.  Worked for me, too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you do it from from gmail you can do it on a by sender basis. Here are the instructions: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/v0rJQjdR-Pc

> click show details then click Images from this sender are always
>   displayed. Don't display from now on.
>
> NOTE YOU WILL ONLY SEE THAT OPTION IF THERE ARE EXTERNALLY LINKED
>   IMAGES - NOT IF THERE ARE INSERTED OR ATTACHED IMAGES

Comment: Please include the instructions in your post, if the link stops working this will be useless.

Comment: Hi, I don't see that option. I went to email details, it only shows, from, to, enctryption, etc.. but no option to not display images.. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Rafael I found these instructions clearer: http://www.prowebguru.com/2015/04/how-to-disable-always-display-images-from-in-gmail/#.WKcCelfR37g

Comment: This solution no longer works.

Comment: I agree with @LS This seems to be outdated and isn't available for me. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103469/undo-always-display-images-from-this-sender#comment126880_103470

Answer (score 2):

In 2020 there is still a working solution to the problem of having accidentally chosen "Always display pictures from this sender" in the Android Gmail app (how I miss Inbox).

Gmail app > Settings > General Settings > Triple Dot Menu > Clear Picture Approvals.

PS I'm adding my answer here even though it's a partial duplicate of another (with lots of up votes). I ignored the other answer since it referenced a specific version of Gmail from 2013 figuring that it was no longer valid. Hopefully this answer will help others like me who skip the other answer.

FYI If all else fails there is a "nuclear option":

Clear the Gmail app's storage

1. Open System Settings app on Android.
2. Find the Gmail app details where you can clear cache and storage (Settings > Apps and Notifications > See all applications > Gmail on Android 10).
3. Choose "Clear storage".

Your stored accounts should persist but the unintended consequence of this action is that all your Gmail settings customizations like more sensible swipe behaviors will be lost. You have to ask yourself if the cure is worse than the disease.